# Linux Bash, get only single word with grep

Tags: bash

I have a large textfile and I have to find all of the "KNR"-alias. I removed all comments and empty lines with this:

```
cat file | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$ >> Test.txt
```

How can I only get this one word, that I need to write out of the "Test.txt" file?
I really only need one word, which has the structure of:
"KNR00000000000000000_THING"
I don´t know if this is possible, but after that structure. there is always a space.

I also need some help with how to make that first line of code work in a script.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Kind regards Elias

Comment: Instead of `cat | grep | grep`,  you could `grep -v '^ *\(#.*\|\)$' <file` !!

Comment: Don't understand exactly what you're looking for, but something like `sed -nE "s/.*(KNR.*) .*/\1/p`?

Comment: @LjmDullaart or `tr < file \  \\n | grep ^KNR`

Comment: @F.Hauri: or `grep -oh 'KNR[^ ]*` , if we understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments:

```
grep -ohE 'KNR[^ ]*' file
```

will use `grep` to match your pattern as I understand it. `[^ ]` means anything but a space.

Other possibilities are `sed`:

```
sed -nE "s/.*(KNR.*) .*/\1/p
```

or @F.Hauri's

```
tr < file \  \\n | grep ^KNR
```

This assumes that the `KNR` is either after a space or at the start of a line.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need this word and noting else, you could do a

```
grep -vE '^#|^$' file | grep -owE KNR0+_THING
```

Of course if there are several words matching this pattern, you get all of them.

Explanation:

-o : Output only the part matching the pattern
-w : Match only words
-E : Turn on extended regex (so that `+` can be used).

I also modified your test for lines to remove.My pattern removes all lines starting with a `#`, and those which contain zero characters.